# Dangling "else" Resolution in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I've been tasked with converting some T-SQL code to C code.  Whoever wrote the code I'm converting indulged in little to no code etiquette.  I know this because of the complete lack of commenting, lack of indentation, and lack of begin/end blocks except where absolutely syntactically necessary (and a few thrown in arbitrarily for good measure).

This raises a few problems.  The code I'm converting is based on the Metaphone algorithm.  I say "based on" because it has quite a few... "undocumented improvements" that make it differ from the official implementation.  Because of this, I can't just go grab some Metaphone implementation, because then it wouldn't actually be a "correct" translation.

So here's the root of the issue(s):

```
if @str1='d'
if substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('dge','dgy','dgi')
set @Result=@Result + 'j'
else
set @Result=@Result + 't'
```

Because of how Metaphone works, I'm pretty sure they meant:

```
if @str1='d'
    if substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('dge','dgy','dgi')
        set @Result=@Result + 'j'
else
    set @Result=@Result + 't'
```

But I'm not sure if it's actually being interpreted as:

```
if @str1='d'
    if substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('dge','dgy','dgi')
        set @Result=@Result + 'j'
    else
        set @Result=@Result + 't'
```

This little snippet isn't too big of a deal, but just after it, there's a section with five "if" statements and only one "else" statement and with no begin/end blocks to explicitly arrange them.  None of this would be a big deal if I could actually run the code to to test and see, but sadly, I don't have an environment to test it and nor do I have any output from previous usage of the code.

**tl;dr:** Do any of you T-SQL gurus out there know which of the above two statements it'll be interpreted as and what's the rule of them with shift/reduce conflicts in T-SQL?  (Attach to first "if" statement, attach to last "if" statement, pick one at random?)

*EDIT:* Here's another fun one a few lines down.

```
if @str1='t'
if substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('tia','tio')
set @Result=@Result + 'x'
else
if @str2='th'
set @Result=@Result + '0'
else
if substring(@str,@cnt,3) <> 'tch'
set @Result=@Result + 't'
```

*EDIT2:* Ok, if I'm reading these answers correctly, that means the above is actually

```
if @str1='t'
    if substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('tia','tio')
        set @Result=@Result + 'x'
    else
        if @str2='th'
            set @Result=@Result + '0'
        else
            if substring(@str,@cnt,3) <> 'tch'
                set @Result=@Result + 't'
```

Comment: That's probably T-SQL code from SQL Server and not PL/SQL code from Oracle. Please change your description and fix your tags.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  The person who assigned it to me said it was PLSQL, but I never bothered to verify.  I don't have experience in either and because it was readable, I never bothered to verify.

Comment: Also "shift/reduce" doesn't really describe the question.  Try "T-SQL if/else nesting question" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that should help you out

```
DECLARE @testvar INT;
DECLARE @testvar2 INT;
SET @testvar = 1;
SET @testvar2 = 1;

IF @testvar = 1
    IF @testvar2 = 1
        SELECT 'Got to 1';
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'Got to 2';
```

If `testvar` and `testvar2` are both 1, it outputs "Got to 1".

If `testvar=1` and `testvar2=2`, it outputs "Got to 2".

If `testvar=2`, there is no output.  So the `else` is getting paired off against the nearest `if`

Comment: No it doesnt! It outputs `Got to 1`!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct.

`IF () IF () X ELSE Y` is equivilent to `IF () BEGIN IF () X ELSE Y END`

The ELSE keyword looks back to the most recent IF statement in the same scope.  So to get what you think was intended, you need to add BEGIN and END statements...

```
IF (@str1='d')
  BEGIN
    IF (substring(@str,@cnt,3) in ('dge','dgy','dgi'))
      SET @Result=@Result + 'j'
  END
ELSE
  SET @Result=@Result + 't'
```

Comment: Thanks for including the Begin/End block in there for clarification.